# Why is not completed transaction in Spring boot on TransactionStatus?

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, commit, rollback

I don't know why is transaction is not completed.

Example)

```
    public void transactionMethod() {
        DefaultTransactionDefinition txDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        txDefinition.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        TransactionStatus testTx = txManager.getTransaction(txDefinition);

        try {
            txManager.commit(testTx);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            log.error("Catch!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
        if (Objects.nonNull(testTx) && !testTx.isCompleted()) {

            txManager.rollback(testTx);
        }

    }
```

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        SimpleTransactionStatus testTx = new SimpleTransactionStatus();
        when(txManager.getTransaction(any())).thenReturn(testTx);

        target.transactionMethod();
    }
```

I think rollback is not implemented because commit ended in try{}. 
However,  `testTx.isCompleted()`is false.....
Could you tell me why `testTx.isCompleted()` is false?